# How to play video and audio using JAVACV

Tags: java, audio, video

I'm trying to make a video player with JavaCV.
After getting the image, I am now trying to get the audio.

Here is my current code:

```
package robomow;  

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception;
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avcodec;
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;

public class client {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    
        FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("rtsp://192.168.101.22:554/stream0?username=UUUUU&password=PPPPP");
        grabber.setImageWidth(960);
        grabber.setImageHeight(540);
        grabber.setFrameRate(25);
        grabber.setOption("rtsp_transport", "tcp");
        grabber.setOption("flags", "nobuffer");
        grabber.setOption("flags", "low_delay");
        grabber.setAudioOption("crf", "0");
        grabber.setAudioBitrate(64000);
        grabber.setSampleRate(8000);
        grabber.setAudioChannels(1);
        grabber.setAudioCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_MULAW);
        
        try {
            grabber.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        final CanvasFrame cFrame = new CanvasFrame("Camera Preview", CanvasFrame.getDefaultGamma() / grabber.getGamma());
        Frame capturedFrame = null;
        
        final AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(grabber.getSampleRate(), 16, grabber.getAudioChannels(), true, true);
        final DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        SourceDataLine soundLine;
        try {
            soundLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            soundLine.open(audioFormat);
            soundLine.start();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        try {
            while ((capturedFrame = grabber.grab()) != null)
            {
                if (cFrame.isVisible())
                {
                    cFrame.showImage(capturedFrame);
                }
            }
            } catch (org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            } 

        cFrame.dispose();
                
        try {
            //soundLine.stop();
            grabber.stop();
            } catch (org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
}
```

The problem is that there is no audio played.
I can hear the audio from the stream using i.e. vlc-player without any issues.

Can anyone advice, please on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is a nice working example for that here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/JavaFxPlayVideoAndAudio.java

Comment: After a while.... I would like to run this example, but I got it terminated with error message: gru 04, 2021 10:12:01 AM mower.JavaFxPlayVideoAndAudio$1 run
SEVERE: null java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0. Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: Please try to ask the author of that code.

Comment: this is done now. it works.